# Adjusting Rich tooltip in Apache Superset

Tags: apache-superset

I'd like to customize the rich tool tip pop up in Apache Superset. Currently the chart I have is this.[image]

Is there anyway to adjust the SUM(total_industry_conversions_standard) to something like 'Industry Conversions'? The data is being pulled as a group by aggregation.

Comment: Can you share the screenshot of Explorer view? I think you can rename your metrics performing the SUM

Answer (score 1):

When you define the metric, you can asign a name to the metric.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UjF1D.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).